# Date Sorting ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Folks, I have a weird requirement. I have an `Object` which consists of a `Date` reference better known as `endDate`. Along with this there is another String field called as the `status` which picks values like '`Soon', 'Ended' and 'Closed'` Such objects are in an ArrayList.

I want to implement a sorting Strategy on this.

First sorting to apply is based on Elapsed time. I want to First sort on EndDate, the difference of which is closest to now should be ranked 1st. i.e if the current Time is `Sep 3,2015 7:34 PM IST` and there exists an object with `endDate` as `Sep 3,2015 7:36 PM IST`.

Second is on the `status` the logic being all object with `soon` should appear first, then the `ended` ones and then `closed`.

Example :
**if the Input is**

```
[0]( Sep 1,2015 10:36 PM IST ,ended)
[1]( Sep 3,2015 7:36 PM IST , soon )
[2]( Aug 29,2015 11:16 AM IST , closed)
[3]( Sep 7,2015 12:00 PM IST , soon )
[4]( Sep 1,2015 12:12 PM IST , ended)
```

**Then the output should be**

```
[0]( Sep 3,2015 7:36 PM IST , soon)
[1]( Sep 7,2015 12:00 PM IST , soon)
[2]( Sep 1,2015 10:36 PM IST ,ended)
[3]( Sep 1,2015 12:12 PM IST , ended)
[4]( Aug 29,2015 11:16 AM IST , closed)
```

*Note : Timestamps used here are for representational purpose only*

**CODE :** The compare implementation inside the comparator, The timestamps are read as GMT.

```
@Override
            public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                try {
                    Date currentdate = dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()));
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Date betEnds1 = dateFormatLocal.parse((String) a.get(KEY_NAME));
                    Date betEnds2 = dateFormatLocal.parse((String) b.get(KEY_NAME));


                return betEnds1.compareTo(betEnds2);
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    return -1;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show an attempt made at sorting?

Comment: If you haven't already. Have a look at the Comparator class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html. You can use it with Arrays.sort

Comment: Since the status strings are all going to be predetermined, why not use an enum?

Comment: @Turtle i had written a comparator but its a simple one.

It takes the long representation of time, compares them and returns the ordering. but as i want to have the elapsed time more than 0 first in the list i had put this question. The comparison at which the Objects are sorted is with respect to current time.

And the second sort is on Status

Answer (score 3):

Implement a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and make it sort your items as desired. The `compare(a,b)` method will take two objects and you can either return -1, 0 or +1, depending on whether two items are the same or one is bigger/smaller than the other.